# How to generate OptionParser require arguments

Tags: ruby, optionparser

The code below works, but I am manually raising argument errors for the required arguments using `fetch`, when I want to build the required arguments into the native OptionParser sytax for required parameters:

```
# ocra script.rb -- --type=value
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

  opts.on("--type [TYPE]",String, [:gl, :time], "Select Exception file type (gl, time)") do |t|
    options["type"] = t
  end

  opts.on("--company [TYPE]",String, [:jaxon, :doric], "Select Company (jaxon, doric)") do |t|
    options["company"] = t
  end

end.parse!

opts = {}
opts['type'] = options.fetch('type') do
  raise ArgumentError,"no 'type' option specified  as a parameter (gl or time)"
end

opts['company'] = options.fetch('company') do
  raise ArgumentError,"no 'company' option specified  as a parameter (doric or jaxon)"
end
```

Comment: I found that `"--type [TYPE]"` means TYPE is optional, but `"--type TYPE"` means TYPE is required.
So don't _type_ the brackets f(ಠ‿↼)z

Comment: @xxjjnn, I found that unbracketed `UPPERCASE` values should make the argument required in the documentation as well, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a similar question with an answer that may help you: 
"[How do you specify a required switch (not argument) with Ruby OptionParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541294/how-do-you-specify-a-required-switch-not-argument-with-ruby-optionparser/1542658#1542658)"

In short: there doesn't seem to be a way to make an option required (they are called options after all).

There is an `OptionParser::MissingArgument` exception that you could raise rather than the `ArgumentError` you're currently throwing.

Comment: I have settled on using a ruby gem called https://github.com/JEG2/highline this has a cli menu dsl and required params.

Comment: Nice work. A colleague of mine also wrote a gem called escort which can set required parameters for CLI apps: https://github.com/skorks/escort#required-arguments

Answer (score 5):

Faced with the same situation, I ended up with an option like this. If not all of my mandatory options are provided, output the user-friendly help text generated by `OptionParser` based on my defined options. Feels cleaner than throwing an exception and printing a stack trace to the user.

```
options = {}
option_parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: #{$0} --data-dir DATA_DIR [options]"

  # A non-mandatory option
  opts.on('-p', '--port PORT', Integer, 'Override port number') do |v|
    options[:port] = v
  end

  # My mandatory option
  opts.on('-d', '--data-dir DATA_DIR', '[Mandatory] Specify the path to the data dir.') do |d|
    options[:data_dir] = d
  end
end

option_parser.parse!

if options[:data_dir].nil?
  puts option_parser.help
  exit 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a simple method for the `options` to validate required parameters in a more readable manner. This method enables you to define human-readable error messages for better clarity. Here's how it works:

```rb
options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: your script [options]"
  opts.on("-n", "--name NAME", "Reporter name. Human-readable name that will be used in a report") do |n|
    options[:name] = n 
  end
  opts.on("-u", "--username USERNAME", "GitHub username. For example, 'volodya-lombrozo'") do |u|
    options[:username] = u
  end
  opts.on("-p", "--position", "Reporter position in a company. Default value is a 'Software Developer'.") do |p|
    options[:position] = p
  end
end.parse!

# Custom method to raise an exception with a human-readable message
def options.require_option(key, message)
  raise OptionParser::MissingArgument, message if self[key].nil?
end

# Check for required options
options.require_option(:name, "Reporter name is required. Please specify using -n or --name.")
options.require_option(:username, "GitHub username is required. Please specify using -u or --username.")
```

This code snippet enhances the readability of option validation by providing informative error messages. If any required option is missing, it will raise an `OptionParser::MissingArgument` exception with the specified message.